# Either checkbox isn't checked OR script stops from continuing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

1. I want the user to just click the row, which will then check or uncheck the checkbox.
2. I want the row to animate and move up or down, so that the the checked items appear in the bottom of the list.

All of this works fine! :-)

But when I click on the actual checkbox, it's not checked.
I have tried with stopPropagation, but it just stops the animation instead.

I have tried tons of things, but none of it works. :-(

What to do?? :/

You can see a demo here:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.row').click(function (){
  var checkbox = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
  checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop("checked"));
  
  var upordown = checkbox.prop("checked");
  if(upordown){
   $( this ).slideUp(function() {$( this ).insertAfter( "#foo" );
      $( this ).slideDown();
       });
   }
  else{
   
   $( this ).slideUp(function() {$( this ).insertBefore( "#foo" );
      $( this ).slideDown();
    });
   }
 });
 
// $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function (e)
// {
//  e.stopPropagation();
//  return true;
// });
 
});
```

```css
.row {
 width: 300px;
 padding: 4px;
 margin: 2px;
  border:1px solid #666;
}
.left {
 float: left;
 width: 25px;
}
.clear {
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">Todo</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1"/>
  </div>
  <div class="center">Item1</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">
    <input type="checkbox" value="2"/>
  </div>
  <div class="center">Item2</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">
    <input type="checkbox" value="4"/>
  </div>
  <div class="center">Item3</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">
    <input type="checkbox" value="6"/>
  </div>
  <div class="center">Item4</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">
    <input type="checkbox" value="11"/>
  </div>
  <div class="center">Item5</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="foo" style="Display: none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it was a bubbling event issue. Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".row, input[type='checkbox']").click(function(e) {
    var row;
    if ($(e.target).is(".row")) {
      row = $(e.target);
    } else {
      row = $(e.target).closest(".row");
    }
    var checkbox = $('input[type=checkbox]', row);
    checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop("checked"));

    var up = checkbox.prop("checked");
    if (up) {
      row.slideUp(function() {
        row.insertAfter("#foo").slideDown();
      });
    } else {
      row.slideUp(function() {
        row.insertBefore("#foo").slideDown();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 25px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-wrapper">
  <div class="row">Todo</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
    </div>
    <div class="center">Item1</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      <input type="checkbox" value="2" />
    </div>
    <div class="center">Item2</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      <input type="checkbox" value="4" />
    </div>
    <div class="center">Item3</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      <input type="checkbox" value="6" />
    </div>
    <div class="center">Item4</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      <input type="checkbox" value="11" />
    </div>
    <div class="center">Item5</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="foo" style="Display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

This works as expected. Since the `row` element may not be the click target, we may want to address that to make sure we have selected the correct element.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! So you are using closest instead of find. Much better! I have been struggling for two days. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @StuckAtDatQ it's relative. `.find()` will find an element in the children of the selected. `.closest()` will traverse the parent elements until it finds the target element. Since the Target in this case could be a number of `DIV` elements, I created a condition to check and do one or the other.